# Does react-native has good slider library for android tv?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'have tried to find slider library for android TV which is compatible with directional pad. I tried to use @react-native-community/slider but this code:

```
        <Slider onSlidingComplete={onPlaybackStatusUpdate} value={status.positionMillis} maximumValue={status.durationMillis}/>
```

does not worked with directional pad. For some reason these events worked only with taps or mouse(on simulator)

Does react-native has some library which can support it? Or how can i solve that issue?